# XSL stylesheet active content being blocked by browser

Tags: javascript, css, xml, internet-explorer, xslt

Hi I have an XSL stylesheet I am using to transform an XML document see [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012367/how-to-create-collapsable-expandable-menutree-from-xml-using-xsl)
The transform works beautifully, the treeview expands and collapses when the user clicks on the nodes just as advertised. However on some of the client machines I've run it on has active content disabled (IE8/9), The message being

> *IE has restricted this file from showing active content...*

It's easy enough to just click *allow blocked content...* However on the machines in question this **CANNOT**(absolutely) **MUST** not be done. It's verboten. I can't go changing the browser settings
My question is how can I get around this *without* changing browser settings.

Can I do the transform on the "server side" basically using lxml to transform  the XML something like

```
import lxml.etree as ET
dom = ET.parse(xml_filename)
xslt = ET.parse(xsl_filename)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

Will that allow for the resulting xml shown on the client machine to remain dynamic?
Do I need to fire up a little python webserver?
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: serve it from http, not a file

Comment: ok, could you walk me through exactly what that means. how can I go about "serving" the xml and xsl from http? Assume very VERY rudimentary knowledge of how websites,html,javascript,webservers work. Step by step would be great

Comment: at it's most basic, setup IIS in windows>control>programs>turn window's features on and off, copy your documents to the www_root you choose, and visit at localhost://filename.html. google "simple http server" for tons of more specific walkthroughs.

Comment: Ahh thanks, though in this case I cannot change browser settings much less go around client machines turning on and off windows features. But what your saying sounds like I should look into embedding a webserver in my application that can server the xml/xsl file from, as I lean towards Python I assume SimpleHTTPServer is where your advice is leading?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can I get around this without changing browser settings.

Use a self-contained stylesheet. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="html5.xml"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                >
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" version="" indent="yes" standalone="no" media-type="text/html" omit-xml-declaration="no" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
      These<br/>words<br/>are<br/>seperated<br/>by<br/>BRs
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This self-contained stylesheet works when saved as html5.xml.

**References**

- [Self-Referencing Stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/Math/XSL/Overview-tech.html#self-style)